# perform operations on custom html data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of items in a `<ul>` as follows:

```
<li class="word" id="apple" data-letters="5" draggable="true">apple</li>
<li class="word" id="ball" data-letters="4" draggable="true">ball</li>
```

I want to be able to drag these items into other `<ul>`s (currently doing this using jQueryUI sortable) and have a function to output the total number of letters (sum of `data-letters` values) in each target `<ul>`...

Can this be done? If so, a few pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, this can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven't really - not sure where to start with setting up the calculation. Presumably as a first step I'd need to be able to get all li elements by class 'word' within ul id 'target1', but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {

            var updateTotal = function(event, ui)
            {
                var total = 0,
                    $list = $(ui.sender);
                $list.find(".word").each(function() {
                    total += Number($(this).attr("data-letters"));
                });
                $("#" + $list.attr("id") + "-totals").html(total);  
            };

    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
                    receive: updateTotal,
                    remove: updateTotal,
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

This assumes that the HTML tag that displays your totals has the id="sortable1-totals" and id="sortable2-totals"

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I'm assuming I could also have this update dynamically by calling this function on the drop event for each li?

Comment: Also, just to confirm... rather than `alert(total);`, can I use `document.getElementById('target1Total').innerHTML = total;`?

Comment: There is a *receive* and *remove* event on the sortable widget.  (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#events)  The ui.sender property is the list.  Also, please read the jQuery tutorials.  $('#target1Total').html(total) would be greatly preferred in jQuery-style development.

Comment: OK, so I now have the following: 

    function totals() {
    var $list1= $('#list1');
    var list1_total= 0;
    $list.find('.word').each(function() {
      list1_total += Number($(this).attr('data-letters'));
    });
    $('#list1_total').html(list1_total);
    var $list2 = $('#list2');
    var list2_total = 0;
    $list.find('.word').each(function() {
      list2_total += Number($(this).attr('data-letters'));
    });
    $('#list2_total').html(list2_total);
    }

Comment: and also:


$(function() {
  $( "#source-list, #list1, #list2" ).sortable({
   receive: function(event, ui) {
            totals();
     },
   connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
 });

Should that be working, or am I doing something dumb?

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate your patience as well as your expertise. :)